# Where do you create new sass variables in Zurb Foundation 6?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Where do you create new sass variables in Zurb Foundation 6, is it in the settings.scss file or do you create a new sass scss file?

Answer (score 1):

I'd create it in settings.scss to keep all my variables in one place, and in case I want to use that variable across other sass files.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Are you using Foundation for a couple of sites for external clients that you want to maintain individually?  If so, then I would suggest using the [Command-Line Tool](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html) with a [Foundation Template](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template).  Each would maintain (under your source control) a separate `_settings.scss` file.

However, if you are working for a company that uses Foundation, you would probably want to maintain the main `_settings.scss` and merge down release changes.

Again, it depends on your process and preference.